# Edit mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, nano

Now, this is a very simple question but I'm new to this topic. To test my website, I'm using a virtual machine (Oracle VM). I'm using ubuntu with apache2. I want to edit mod_rewrite to, of course, rewrite some URLs. But I just don't know how to edit the file, needless to say, there are cat, nano, etc. But I don't know in which folder to go and what file to open. I found the module in /usr/lib/apache2/modules/, but there is nothing readable in it. **So basically, what I'm trying to find is the correct path to a file that I can edit.**
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

rewrite rules are usually in the Apache configuration files. They are usually located in `/etc/apache`, `/etc/apache2` or `/etc/httpd`.

I suggest you start by reading [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/).